# How to center one of nodes in Sigma JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, charts, sigma.js

I'm trying to create a network graph with Sigma JS with minimum edges overlays and with the specific node in the center. I mean, I want to see a preselected node in the center of graph container. For preventing overlays I found [nooverlap plugin](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.layout.noverlap) and [forceAtlas2 plugin](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2), but how can I specify, which node should be in the center?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by setting the x and y positions of the node which you want to be in the center to 0.

If `s` is your sigma instance and `id` is the id of the node you wish to center, you could do this as such:

```
s.graph.nodes(id).x = 0;
s.graph.nodes(id).y = 0;
```

The node will then appear in the center of your canvas. Don't forget to refresh using `s.refresh()` to see the changes.

Comment: Ty, but I need to minimize edges overlaps, so I need something like applying forceAtlas2 algorithm with one node in the center

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you would like to 'pin' this node to the center without being affected by the layout algorithm?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry if I described the issue not enough clear

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?