# How can I center a node in Sigma.js?

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

This same question [was asked five years ago with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042778/how-to-center-one-of-nodes-in-sigma-js), maybe since then there's a solution. I don't understand how formatting works in Sigma.js.

Maybe sigma isn't the right tool for the job? I thought I'd be able to accomplish something like this (except maybe a little prettier than my MS paint sketch):

[image]

But Simga doesn't seem to want to be anchored like I imagined. For example, with the example code on the library's website:

```js
var s = new sigma('container');

// Then, let's add some data to display:
s.graph.addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'n0',
  label: 'Hello',
  // Display attributes:
  x: 0.5,
  y: 0.5,
  size: 1,
  color: '#f00'
}).addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'n1',
  label: 'World !',
  // Display attributes:
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  size: 1,
  color: '#00f'
}).addEdge({
  id: 'e0',
  // Reference extremities:
  source: 'n0',
  target: 'n1'
});

// Finally, let's ask our sigma instance to refresh:
s.refresh();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.1/sigma.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Since it seems Sigma treats x and y position as a range between 0 and 1, it seemed to me if I put 0.5 for x and y coords, I should get a node in the center. But instead, you see the result.

So is sigma the wrong tool for the job, and if not, how do I approach this problem? I'm not asking for someone to write all the code for me, I'm just trying to understand how this library works.

Comment: are you looking to draw an exact image of given picture using sigma js?

Comment: @DeepuReghunath not exact, it's just depicting the basic layout

Comment: does the below answer gives you an idea of how to draw the rest of the nodes?

Comment: @DeepuReghunath Yes. Unfortunately I now realize Sigma.js does not expose the pixel coordinates of the nodes on Canvas to the user, so it's impossible for certain features (like packets represented by little squares rendered flowing between two nodes) to be integrated without a lot of effort studying and modifying the Sigma source code. I'll have to find another tool.

Comment: you want to represent a square in between the center nodes. right?

Comment: @DeepuReghunath well not quite that simple, I want to make squares (representing packets) flow over the path between two nodes over time, as an animation. I intended to overlay a canvas and read the positions of the nodes in order to render the packets somewhere between the two nodes for each timestep in an animation. So not only show a square, but choose what position it shows up between two nodes.

Is that possible through sigma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodes in the sigma are drawing based on the `x y z` coordinate value. and the line between the nodes(called edge) is drawn by giving the source and the target node.

```js
var s = new sigma('container');

// Then, let's add some data to display:
s.graph.addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'n0',
  label: 'Hello',
  // Display attributes:
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  size: 2,
  color: '#f00'
}).addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'n1',
  label: 'World !',
  // Display attributes:
  x: 1,
  y: 0,
  size: 2,
  color: '#00f'
}).addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'a1',
  label: 'a1',
  // Display attributes:
  x: 1.05,
  y: -0.20,
  size: 2,
  color: '#00f',
  target:''
}).addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'a2',
  label: 'a2',
  // Display attributes:
  x: 0.90,
  y: -0.25,
  size: 2,
  color: '#00f',
}).addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'a3',
  label: 'a3',
  // Display attributes:
  x: 1.15,
  y: -0.30,
  size: 2,
  color: '#00f',
}).addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'a4',
  label: 'a4',
  // Display attributes:
  x: 1.15,
  y: -0.13,
  size: 2,
  color: '#00f',
}).addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'a5',
  label: 'a5',
  // Display attributes:
  x: 1.25,
  y: 0.15,
  z: 0,
  size: 2,
  color: '#00f',
}).addNode({
  // Main attributes:
  id: 'b1',
  label: 'b1',
  // Display attributes:
  x: -0.25,
  y: -0.15,
  z: 0,
  size: 2,
  color: '#f00',
}).addEdge({
  id: 'e0',
  // Reference extremities:
  source: 'n0',
  target: 'n1'
}).addEdge({
  id: 'e1',
  // Reference extremities:
  source: 'n1',
  target: 'a1'
}).addEdge({
  id: 'e2',
  // Reference extremities:
  source: 'a1',
  target: 'a2'
}).addEdge({
  id: 'e3',
  // Reference extremities:
  source: 'a1',
  target: 'a3'
}).addEdge({
  id: 'e4',
  // Reference extremities:
  source: 'a1',
  target: 'a4'
}).addEdge({
  id: 'e5',
  // Reference extremities:
  source: 'n1',
  target: 'a5'
}).addEdge({
  id: 'eb1',
  // Reference extremities:
  source: 'n0',
  target: 'b1'
});

// Finally, let's ask our sigma instance to refresh:
s.refresh();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.1/sigma.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```